# Change MPMoviePlayer seeking rate

Tags: iphone, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, reverse, rate

I was wondering if it was at all possible to to change the seeking of movie.

I see this

```
enum {
MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped,
MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying,
MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused,
MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted,
MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward,
MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward };
```

For the seeking each time it goes about 5 0r 6 seconds. I was wondering if I could change that to seek less. like .1 of a second. What I am trying to do is play a video backwards. i notices on the mac quicktime if you hold the reverse the video will play backwards. I tried the same on my phone. If you hold it it will skip backwards, not just jump to the beginning. I just don't want the skipping part. Even if it is a little sketchy that is still ok, better than what it is now.

Any ideas?
Or am I missing something like movie player.playback = reverse or something like that?

Thanks in advanced!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

The property currentPlaybackRate (declared in MPMediaPlayback.h) is a float which you can set to adjust your playback speed. *eg:*

```
                self.moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackRate = -12.0f;
```